# Understanding the Concept of Central Series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading Hungerford's book *Algebra*, in which it defines a central series as follows:

> Let $G$ be a group. Define $C_1(G)=C(G)$. Then define $C_i(G)$ inductively as the inverse image of $C(G/C_{i-1}(G))$ under the canonical projection $G\to G/C_{i-1}(G)$. Then the sequence of normal groups $C_1(G)<C_2(G)<\cdots<C_n(G)<\cdots$ is called the **central series** of $G$.

> Remark: The notation $C(G)$ is the center of $G$.

However I met another definition of central series. It goes as follows:

> A **central series** is a normal series $1\lhd N_1\lhd N_2\lhd\cdots\lhd N_r=G$ such that $G/N_{i-1}<C(N_i/N_{i-1})$.

I could show that in the first definition, we have $C_i(G)/C_{i-1}(G)=C(G/C_{i-1}(G))$. However, how can I show that the second definition implies the first one (whence these two definitions are equivalent)? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I think the first definition is usually called an upper central series, and the second definition is called a central series (I think it should say $N_i/N_{i-1} < C(G/N_{i-1})$ instead?). For a proof of equivalence, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4111176